# Different Pytorch random initialization with the same seed

Tags: python, random, pytorch

I am very new to Pytorch, so I apologise if the question is very straightforward.
My problem is that I have defined class `net1` and initialised its parameters randomly with a fixed manual seed.

```
random.seed(opt.manualSeed)
torch.manual_seed(opt.manualSeed)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(opt.manualSeed)    

class net1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net1, self).__init__()
        self.main_body = nn.Sequential(
            # Define the layers...#
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.main_body(x)

# custom weights initialization called on net1
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        m.weight.data.normal_(0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        m.weight.data.normal_(1.0, 0.02)
        m.bias.data.fill_(0)

net1_ = net1()
net1_.apply(weights_init)
```

However, when I add another class `net2` to the code:

```
class net2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net2, self).__init__()
        self.main_body = nn.Sequential(
            # Define the layers
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.main_body(x)

net2_ = net2()
```

and instantiate it, even though I do not use it anywhere else and it is not connected to my main graph (which is built on `net1_`), I get different outputs from my graph.
Is it a reasonable outcome?

Comment: Fix the seed a second time before instantinating net2?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the order of execution is:

```
random.seed(opt.manualSeed)
torch.manual_seed(opt.manualSeed)
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(opt.manualSeed)    

if with_net2:
    net2_ = net2()

net1_ = net1()
net1_.apply(weights_init)
```

If so, this is expected.

This is because when `net2.__init__` is called (during `net2_ = net2()`), 
torch's random number generator is used to randomly initialize weights in `net2_`.
Therefore the state of the random number generator at the execution `net1_.apply` would be different if `with_net2 = True` as compared to `with_net2 = False`.